# Eslint parsing error when exporting submodules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm working on an npm package, which is structured like the following:

index.js

```
export foo from 'foo'
export bar from 'bar'
```

foo.js

```
export default { foo: true }
```

bar.js

```
export default { bar: true }
```

However when I run eslint I get the following error:
`1:0  error  Parsing error: Declaration or statement expected`

Anyone know how to fix this? Here is my eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest/globals": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint",
        "jest"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Thanks